# Notify owner of post and other commenters

Tags: performance, ruby, ruby-on-rails, mvc

I have a rails4 app. When a user comments on a post it should send a notification to all the guys who commented on the post and to the post creator. I have a working method in the controller, but it's kinda ugly and I'd like to refactor it.

Could somebody tell me what the rails convention for refactoring this?

Comment belongs_to :post, post has_many :comments

```
create#comment action 

    if @post_comment.save
      ((@post.users + [@post.user]).uniq - [current_user]).each do |post_commenter|
        Notification.create(recipient_id: post_commenter.id, sender_id: current_user.id, notifiable: @post_comment.post, action: "commented")
    end
    ....
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would add a method to `Post`:

```
# app/models/post.rb
def notify_others_about_new_comment(comment)
  recipients = [user]               # the author of the original post
  recipients << users               # people that wrote a comment
  recipients.delete(comment.user)   # writer of the new comment

  recipients.uniq.each do |recipient|
    Notification.create(
      recipient_id: recipient.id, 
      sender_id: comment.user.id, 
      notifiable: self, 
      action: 'commented'
    )
  end
end
```

And just call that method in your controller:

```
if @post_comment.save
  @post.notify_others_about_new_comment(@post_comment)
  #...
end
```

Comment: spickermann, you mistyped it. you use `comment.user` instead of `current_user`. Could you correct it for other who may check this solution? I have 2 questions as well. 1.  Is `recipients.delete(current_user)` better than `recipients - [current_user]` or it's just a matter of taste? 2. How do you decide on which instance you call the method from `post`, `post_comment` and `current_user`?

Comment: I decided to add the method to `Post` and call it on `@post`, because it felt to my that belongs into post, because a post is the instant that should (or could) know about all users involved into this conversation. There is no need for a `comment` or a `current_user` to know about other commenters. I think you should not pass `current_user` to that method. A comment, should know who the author was and I guess `comment.user` equals `current_user`, doesn't it? I prefer `delete` over `-` because it reads better.

Comment: So you think I always should use in these kind of cases `object.user` over `current_user`? I usually use `current_user` because it's more readable, but if you know any reason not to do so, then I will change it.

Comment: `current_user` only exists in the context of a controller. Whereas `object.user` exists in the model. If we want to move this functionality from the controller into the model (following *Skinny Controller, Fat Model* pattern) than you have to use `object.user` and cannot use `current_user`.

Comment: might also consider adding `after_create :notify_others_about_new_comment` and omitting that method call from the controller

Comment: I disagree on using a `after_create` callback. In my experience callbacks like that lead to problems, when you for example need to import data (and do not want to notify users), when moderators/admins edit posts or while testing (it makes your test slow or you have to stub the callback every time you need to generate a comment in a test).

Answer (score 1):

As you tagged your question with "performance" and the notification creation process needs not to be very real-time, I think it's better to move it to the background. For example, you can create one or more processes which focus on creating notifications when they received messages. Rails application send messages to those processes through a message broker like RabbitMQ.

Comment: Aetherus, at the moment I'm doing it real-time with pusher. Maybe it's not the best idea, but I wan't users to get the notification right away without page load.

Comment: This feels very slim for an answer, can you expand on how that's an improvement over the existing solution?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two possible solutions: Using a service object, or adding this to your `Post` class and utilizing Active Record callbacks.

### Using a service object

As you'll see in a moment, there isn't much in the service object except a way to send these notifications. While there isn't much code, what you'll gain is decoupling code that interacts solely with your own system (your models and database) from code that interacts with outside resources (notifications).

First, to centralize the logic of finding the post users, without the post author, add a method to the Post class:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def other_users
    users - user
  end
end
```

Then the service object:

```
class PostService
  def add_comment(post, author, comment_text)
    new_comment = post.comments.create user: author, text: comment_text
    post.other_users.each { |user| CommentNotification.create user, new_comment }
    new_comment
  end
end
```

And your controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    post = Post.find params[:comment][:post_id]
    author = User.find params[:comment][:user_id]
    @comment = post_service.add_comment author, params[:comment][:text]

    if post.save
      redirect_to post_url(post)
    else
      render action: 'create'
    end
  end

  private

  def post_service
    @post_service ||= PostService.new
  end
end
```

### Using ActiveRecord callbacks

Honestly my initial reaction was to use an `after_save` callback, but I also read spickermann's comment about shying away from ActiveRecord callbacks. While I've had problems with callbacks before, if you construct your code correctly, the callback shouldn't be a problem. I also don't think the controller should know much of anything about posts, comments or notifications. The controller should handle the basics of the HTTP request, and little more.

Adding an `add_comment` method to the Post class would be the appropriate place to enforce this logic:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :send_comment_notifications

  def add_comment(author, text, notify_users = true)
    new_comment = Comment.new(post: self, user: author, text: text)
    comments << new_comment

    other_users.each do |user|
      comment_notifications << CommentNotification.create user, new_comment
    end if notify_users

    return new_comment
  end

  private

  def comment_notifications
    @comment_notifications ||= []
  end

  def other_users
    users - user
  end

  def send_commend_notifications
    comment_notifications.each do |notification|
      notification.send
    end

    @comment_notifications = nil
  end
end
```

The `notify_users` argument, `true` by default, allows you to disable notifications which solves Spickermann's major complaint about spamming notifications if you need to do a data import.

---

Aside: I took a few liberties with your other classes, so they might not exactly match your object model, but you should get the main idea.

---

- The users you want to notify are the users for the post, excluding the creator of the post. I think that is best encapsulated in its own method: `other_users`
- Create a class called `CommentNotification` which inherits from `Notification`, and place all logic for constructing that notification in there making this portable.

  ```
  class CommentNotification < Notification
    NOTIFICATION_ACTION = 'commented'

    def self.create(user, comment)
      base.create(
        recipient_id: user.id,
        sender_id: comment.post_user_id,
        notifiable: comment.post,
        action: NOTIFICATION_ACTION)
    end
  end
  ```
- The controller becomes extremely slim:

  ```
  class PostCommentsController < ApplicationController
    def create
      post = Post.find params[:comment][:post_id]
      author = User.find params[:comment][:user_id]
      @comment = post.add_comment author, params[:comment][:text]

      if post.save
        redirect_to post_url(post)
      else
        render action: 'create'
      end
    end
  end
  ```

Comment: Greg, you mentioned service objects, but as far as I see this is the callback solution. Could you show it with service object? I would avoid using callbacks.

Comment: @SzilardMagyar: I added a service object example to my answer as well.